# Flash object controlled with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

I am trying to wrap a video to be used for a site background within a Flash Movie. When the user clicks on a list of  elements I need the video to play and pause at pre-defined frames . Is it possible to control swf playback with JavaScript?

In particular, I need:

- The Flash object must fire a Javascript event when preloaded, so that I can fadeIn() a series of divs with JQuery
- A click on a HTML anchor must play the video and make it pause at a certain point

Can you point out any known compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The communication in both ways is possible and easy to implement.

There is an Actionscript class called `ExternalInterface` which makes the whole process almost painless.

Check [the examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Comment: I hope you mean painless instead of painfull? Quick addition: don't forget to add allowScriptAccess as 'param' in the html embed-code.